# Sending a variable in the form helper(CodeIgniter)

Tags: codeigniter

i want to send variables when using the codeIgniter form helper.

The function in the controller takes two variables like:

```
public function doSomething($var1, $var2){

...

}
```

In the form helper I want to do something like this:

```
echo form_open('Controller/doSomething($var1, $var2)');
echo form_submit('doIt', 'Do it');
```

How can I do this because the above doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hidden Fields

```
echo form_open('controller/method', array('id'=>'id'), array('var1'=>$var1));
```

OR

## Via Route

```
echo form_open("controller/method/$var1/$var2", array('id'=>'id'));
```